# How can I read a web page with Html Agility Pack

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, html-agility-pack

I want to read a web page by this library but some page has a script that in first level run script ( for example Welcome or site is loading or … ) then in second level show page content.
And in this page this library I access just the first level.

```
string linkUrl = "yoursite.come";
  var doc = new HtmlWeb().Load(linkUrl);
   var pTags = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("p").Select(el => el.InnerText)
           .Where(u => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(u.ToString()));
// Any Code about pTags
```

Comment: HTML agility pack can only parse HTML. AFAIK there is no Javascript support. You may need to use another solution like Selenium.

Comment: Is there any reason to use agility pack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Html Agility Pack don't support JavaScript so you need to use alternative libraries that have JavaScript support.

1. **[AngleSharp](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp.Io)** is a fast, extensible, and well-documented HTML parser that supports JavaScript. It is also very tolerant of malformed HTML.
2. **[CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery)** is a lightweight HTML parser that uses XPath queries to select elements from an HTML document. It also supports JavaScript.
3. **[dotless](https://github.com/dotless/dotless)** is a pure-.NET HTML parser that is designed to be fast and easy to use. It also supports JavaScript.

these libraries can help you solve your issue.